# Trouble finding a function satisfying an integral equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm stuck at the last step of this exercise:

> b) Use the Banach fixed point theorem to show that there is a unique function $f \in C[0,1]$ for which the equation $$f(t) + \int_0^1e^{\tau+t-3}f(\tau)d\tau = 1 \quad \forall t \in [0,1]$$ holds. Determine $f$. Use the fact that $(X,\|\cdot \|_{\infty})$ is a Banach space.

I already proved existence of $f$ with the fixed point theorem. However, I am stuck determinating $f$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Notice
$$ \int_0^1 e^{\tau + t - 3} f(\tau) \, d\tau = e^t \int_0^1 e^{\tau - 3} f(\tau) \, d\tau .$$
So the equation can be rewritten as
$$ f(t) = 1 - C e^t  ,\tag 1$$
where 
$$ C = \int_0^1 e^{\tau - 3} f(\tau) \, d\tau .\tag 2$$
Now substitute equation (1) into equation (2), and solve for $C$.

Comment: Can you maybe give me the first step?

Comment: Use $e^{t + \tau - 3} = e^t e^{\tau -3}$.  Then pull the $e^t$ out of the integral.  You can do this because it doesn't depend on $\tau$.